# Extension for fractional Sobolev spaces, s>0

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, besov-spaces, linear-extensions

In their paper, [Fractional Sobolev extension and imbedding](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2015-367-02/S0002-9947-2014-06088-1/S0002-9947-2014-06088-1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwim58DN6K77AhUCUsAKHdsxDAUQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1epkRKCdptw3FfM4tRYBvH), the author describes all extension domains for $s \in (0,1)$ -- meaning spaces functions in which are not required to have weak derivatives. Is there an obvious extension to $s>0$, or is it an open problem? If so, is it an open problem for $p=2$?

P.S. (feel free to skip) This appears to be a common setting across results on fractional Sobolev spaces; some make statements for $s>0$ and present the proof for $s \in (0,1)$, with a comment that the extension is trivial. I am missing how it is trivial. (I realise this part of the question is vague as I'm not stating these results. Feel free to ignore.)

Comment: I know the paper you quote very well and I do not understand your question. "Is it an open problem?" What open problem? $p=2$? There is nothing special about $p=2$. The problem is with $s$. Extending results from $s\in (0,1)$ to all $s>0$ is almost never trivial. Where did you find such a statement? I am voting to close the problem. You shoudl delte it and reformulate in a different way.

Comment: In fact, the linked paper itself already comments on arising difficulties for $s=1$ or $s \in \mathbb{N}$ in general.. (Remarks 1.3&1.4)